# IPv6 FTP blocked by UFW

Tags: server, 16.10, firewall, ftp, ufw

I am setting up a FTP server. It works perfectly over IPv4, however when connecting via IPv6 I'm getting blocked by UFW.

My UFW rules:

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
873                        ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
873 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Did I do something wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that the firewall is your problem, however, you could temporarily disable the firewall, retest, and prove that out. More than likely your path/router isn't supporting IPv6.

Comment: Well I did exactly that! HTTP over IPv6 works perfectly, but FTP over IPv6 doesn't. If I disable the firewall it works. And also, it shows up in the logs as the IP address got blocked. So, what did I do wrong? :)

Comment: So IPv6 FTP works with the firewall disabled, yes? Install `gufw` and see how the rules look there.